# How to calculate the cost of a Google dataflow?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

My company is evaluating if we can use Google Dataflow.

I have run a dataflow on Google Cloud Platform. The console shows 5 hr 25 minutes in "Reserved CPU Time" field on the right.

> Worker configuration: n1-standard-4
>
> Starting 8 workers...

How to calculate the cost of the dataflow ? According to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing#two)
the price is $0.01  per GCEU per hr,  how can I find the number of GCEU consumed by my dataflow, and the number of hours?

[image: Cloud Dataflow Console]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the number of GCEUs per machine here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types. For example, n1-standard-4s are 11 GCEUs.

The cost of a batch Dataflow job (in addition to the raw cost of VMs) is then

```
(Reserved CPU time in hours) / (Cores per machine) * (GCEUs) * $.01
```

Then, the total cost of the job is

```
(machine hours) * ((GCEUs) * $.01 + (machine cost per hour) + (PD cost per hour for attached disks))
```

For example, for n1-standard-4 with 250GB disks, this works out to (11 * $.01 + $.152 + ($.04 * 250 / 30 / 24)) = $.276 per machine-hour.

Comment: Thank you, could you extend your equation and include calculation of the raw cost of VMs to produce the total ? I need the total cost of the dataflow.

Comment: There is a new pricing model for Dataflow since 2018-05-03. See post below.

Answer (score 0):

There is [new pricing model for Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing) since 2018-05-03.

Now you should use following formula:

```
(vcpu_hours * vcpu_hourly_price) +
(mem_hours  * mem_hourly_price) +
(disk_hours * disk_hourly_price)
```

Additional costs for Shuffle may apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable [billing export to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-setup) it's possible and easy to compute the cost of a single Dataflow job with the query below filling in the correct values for `GCP_PROJECT`, `BILLING_TABLE_NAME` and `DATAFLOW_JOB_ID`. The query is:

```
SELECT
  l.value AS job_id,
  ROUND(SUM(cost),3) AS cost 
FROM `$GCP_PROJECT.$BILLING_TABLE_NAME` bill, UNNEST(bill.labels) l
WHERE service.description = 'Cloud Dataflow' and l.value = `$DATAFLOW_JOB_ID`
GROUP BY 1;
```

You can find the value for `DATAFLOW_JOB_ID` in the Dataflow UI and `BILLING_TABLE_NAME` in the BigQuery UI. The `BILLING_TABLE_NAME` will be of the format `gcp_billing_export_resource_$ACCOUNT_ID`

NOTE: From personal experience it seems to take quite a while before the billing table is populated with the pricing information.